# MySQL Query Case When for 30 Days, 60 Days, and Not Scheduled output

Tags: mysql

I have built the following query to try & do the following:

1. If omSchedDate = 0 to 30 days of today then flag "30 Days"
2. If omSchedDate = 31 to 60 days of today then flag "60 Days"
3. If omSchedDate falls before 0 days of today OR after 60 Days then flag "Not Scheduled"

   ```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(tblcom.omSchedDate, CURDATE()) AS age,

   CASE 
   WHEN tblcom.omSchedDate > CURDATE() AND tblcom.omSchedDate < (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),
   INTERVAL 31 DAY))THEN '30 Days'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), tblcom.omSchedDate) > 30 THEN '60 Days'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), tblcom.omSchedDate) <= 0 then 'Not Scheduled'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), tblcom.omSchedDate) IS NULL then 'Not Scheduled'
   ELSE NULL
   END AS consch

   FROM      tblcom 
   ORDER BY tblcom.omSchedDate
   ```

My query above gives me the right output for the 30 Days column, but the "60 Days" & "Not Scheduled" columns are not correct?

```
Age, conSch
-728,60 Days
-726,60 Days
-715,60 Days
-666,60 Days
-102,60 Days
-88,60 Days
-46,60 Days
-15,
-14,
-5,
-4,
2,30 Days
3,30 Days
6,30 Days
14,30 Days
27,30 Days
28,30 Days
30,30 Days
41,Not Scheduled
41,Not Scheduled
83,Not Scheduled
188,Not Scheduled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues here.  First, you have the order of subtraction reversed in your `DATEDIFF` operations.  It should be:

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) > 30 THEN '60 Days'
WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) < 0 THEN 'Not Scheduled'
```

Second, you don't have a check for a difference greater than 60 days, so you need to add that AND you need to add it before the check for over 30 days, or else values greater than 60 will never reach that check.

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) > 60 THEN 'Not Scheduled'
```

Third, if omSchedDate can possibly be NULL (which is the only way your final `DATEDIFF` line could end up null), then you should really check for that first to prevent possible errors:

```
CASE
WHEN omSchedDate IS NULL THEN 'Not Scheduled'
```

and you might as well translate your other line to a `DATEDIFF` as well, leaving you with:

```
CASE
    WHEN omSchedDate IS NULL THEN 'Not Scheduled'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '30 Days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) > 60 THEN 'Not Scheduled'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) > 30 THEN '60 Days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) < 0 THEN 'Not Scheduled'
    ELSE NULL
END AS consch
```

Comment: dg99, beautiful.. your code did the trick with just one typo:
- END CASE AS consch 
should be:
- END AS consch

Comment: Good point.  I was mixing up the [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) and the CASE expression.  I have fixed it.

Comment: Hey dg99, what if I need the negative values only to be flagged as "n/a" ?

Comment: duh.. just changed WHEN DATEDIFF(omSchedDate, CURDATE()) < 0 THEN 'n/a'

Comment: If you find my response to have answered your question, then please Accept it so other users will know it's not still open.